# このサイトのフッターにある「法律」という言葉は「利用規約」にしたほうがいいのでは？

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

このサイトのフッターには「ヘルプ」「プライバシーポリシー」「採用情報」「お問い合わせ」などのリンクが存在します。

ところがここに「法律」という一般的なサイトには見られない言葉が存在しており、そのリンクをクリックするとスタックオーバーフローの利用規約と思われる説明が英語でずらりと書かれています。

この「法律」という単語は「利用規約」としたほうがいいのでは？

[image: スタックオーバーフローのフッター]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

legalが法律と訳されていたようです。

[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/$/40286487?key=2fbd4ee396cdac223059952a7fe01e54)上で修正したので、近日中に反映されるかと思います。